# Best way to plot multiple similar lines?

Tags: data-visualization

I have come up with the following way of showing 8 (roughly similar) line plots on the same figure. I was wondering if there was a better/more compressed way to do it. Plotting them on top of each other is too messy, as it is becomes very hard to distinguish them.

[image: 8 lines]

Comment: Is it really too messy if you don't fill the area under the curve? Seems like it would be a 8 lines with a similar trajectory but different heights so you'd see most of the lines and they wouldn't cross much. That the overlap a lot except at the peaks would be part of the point of showing them

Comment: Well, in the final figure I will have 21 curves actually. Here there are only 8.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps something like the figure below would be a better fit, especially when the number of curves increases.

[image]

Source [kde_ridgeplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/kde_ridgeplot.html)